# PowerShell script to write out recursive list of files without the root directory

Tags: powershell, directory

Is there an easy way of stripping the root directory when retrieving a recursive list of files in a directory?

e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Test\Folder" | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select FullName | Out-File "C:\Test\Folder\items.txt"
```

But instead of this giving me:

```
 C:\Test\Folder\shiv.png
 C:\Test\Folder\Another\kendall.png
 C:\Test\Folder\YetAnother\roman.png
```

It gives me:

```
 Folder\shiv.png
 Folder\Another\kendall.png
 Folder\YetAnother\roman.png
```

Is this possible in one line or do I have to write a loop?

Also is there an output method that doesn't create gaps between lines or also spit out the name of the select property at the top? (In this case 'FullName'), or would I just have to loop manually and ignore them?

Comment: So it doesn't give you the absolute path? Also, why would it matter if it's in more than one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with the "gap" is because of Powershell's formatting when displaying objects. If you want to get the plain values, you could use the `-ExpandProperty` switch:

```
select -Expand FullName
```

As for your problem though, you could do something like this:

```
$dir = "C:\Test\Folder"
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -File | foreach {
    $_.FullName.Replace("$dir\", "")
} | Out-File "C:\Test\Folder\items.txt"
```

Note that this would be *case sensitive*. If that's an issue, you could use regex:

```
$dir = "d:\tmp"
$pattern = [Regex]::Escape($dir) + "\\?"
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -File | foreach {
    $_.FullName -replace $pattern, ""
}
```

Comment: I think this outputs the parent folder and the file but not the whole path (excluding the first folder)

Comment: @Remko I don't think you're correct. Have you tried it?

Comment: You've edited it meanwhile, previous version had a regex in it...

Comment: @Remko I've included both versions now, it's really a matter of taste and use-case.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Test\Folder" | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | % { $_.Split("\")[2..1000] -Join "\" }
```

Output:

```
Folder\shiv.png
Folder\Another\kendall.png
Folder\YetAnother\roman.png
```

Explanation:
The result of `Get-ChildItem` is split on the `\` character which returns an array. The next bit `[2..1000]` slices the array from element 2 (and the rest of the array up until the specified number, so just take a sufficiently large number). Finally we join the array into a new string with the `-Join` operator.

Comment: Thankyou - appreciate the explanation - it's not exactly the correct output (It's shuffled C:\ to the front)  but I can see how to split the strings inline now, thanks.

Comment: Ooops I didn't spot that @jimbo but I fixed the code by changing `-1` to `1000` (any number larger than the actual elements will do)